# Why does 3 [4,2] evaluate to undefined in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

To a certain, arguably illogical or derisive, extent I can get my head around JS results like:

```
// Coercing to string and concatenating
3 + [4,2]
'34,2'

// Coercing and doing proper math
4 - [2]
2

// Or failing miserably
3 - [4,2]
NaN
```

But why does `3[4,2]` evaluate to `undefined`? At least in the examples above there are *operations* to perform (**something** is being done). On a related note, ironically `[4,2]3` raises a `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error.

What is happening here?

***Context***: Spent a morning finding and squashing a bug where a `,` (comma) was missing from an array of a mix of numbers and nested arrays: `[1, 2, 3 [4, 2], 5, [8], 7]`.

Comment: Understanding. As explained in the last sentence, I had a bug where a comma was missing from an array declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
3[4,2]
```

is evaluated as

```
(new Number(3))[4, 2]
```

a property lookup operation. The `4,2` expression is an example of the *comma operator*, and its value is the last one in the list of subexpressions, `2`.

The Number instance created by the runtime has no property called "2", so the result is `undefined`.

The language treats the `.` and `[]` operators pretty much the same, though `.` gets tangled up with the token grammar for number literals. The left hand side is converted to an object (if possible; when it's `undefined` you get the familiar "Cannot read property foo of undefined" error). Then the property value is fetched, if it exists.

So for instance

```
3["valueOf"]
```

is not `undefined`: it's a reference to `Number.prototype.valueOf` function.

Comment: Learned something new today. Thank you very much.

Comment: `(+'4.3445')[4, 3, 6, 7, 'toFixed'](2) // '4.34'`. Got it.